# Same URL for multiple routes

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

How can same URL be pointing to different controllers depending on the user role ?

For instance `/route1` should be poiting on `Admin\route1Controller@index` if the user has the admin role, and `OtherRole\route1Controller@index` if the user has the `OtherRole` role.

How can this be done ?

Comment: I think the standard way to do this is to handle the role within the controller method.  So `route1Controller@index` would check if the user is admin or not, then return different views or data

Comment: @Jeff : Thanks, but since I already wrote the different controllers (in subroutes like `role1/route1` and `role2/route1`, should I mix them up in one controller, or is there anything I can use like filters or something ?

Comment: @servabat To get answers relevant to your implementation, you should perhaps post two of your controller actions so we can see the difference in logic between the roles.

Comment: @Bogdan : they are basically totaly different, they return views that have nothing in common base on variables that have nothing in common.

Comment: @servabat Then from my end it makes little sense to have a route path that is named exactly the same, for multiple pieces of logic that are completely different. That's  why I was asking for the code (or at least a detailed explanation), because it offers context and there may be better approaches that can be used that are different from what you're attempting now.

Comment: @Bogdan : For instance imagine want the site index to be different for a normal user and an admin. That's why it makes sense in my case. Maybe should I still have everything in the same controller, but in terms of architecture it made sense to have some separation in my code depending on the type of user (for instance `admin\Controller1` and `role2\Controller1` etc.)

Comment: Well yes, I gathered as much from your initial question :). But how different? Is the interface slightly different with additional options for the admin users? Or completely different, as in a front facing website for normal users and an admin panel for admins? Because it it's the latter, then you should have an `/admin` prefix for the higher privileged users and be done with it.

Comment: @Bogdan : It is more like the latter but there is not such a thing like 'higher privilege', just different thing being displayed (`role1` and `role2` get different things displayed but it's role1 is not hierarchicaly higher than role2).

Comment: Ok, if the roles are hierarchically equal, but require completely different content and logic, then just use a path prefix for each one and let them have their own controller. I'm assuming that `role1` doesn't have access to the same information as `role2` and vice versa (or at least not in the same presented form).

Comment: @Bogdan : Yes it's how I'm working atm, but well routes aren't elegant. But well I guess it's the only solution so .. :/ Thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it by using middleware in routes.php file by creating roles using roman bican roles package in laravel.

Comment: It doesn't allow to have a same URL, you can only filter access to routes based on role.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

You can redirect all user in same controller. But from controller,as per the user type you can redirect in different page.